# how can I achieve the the effect that growing a set of curves and when any curve occurs others' trail, stop it's growth

Tags: processing

i want to achieve like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYnRR.png)

here is my code:

```java
class Particle {
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  PVector initialVelocity;
  ArrayList<PVector> path;
  boolean life = true;
  float q;

  public Particle(PVector position, PVector initialVelocity) {
    this.position = position;
    this.acceleration = new PVector(0, 0);
    this.initialVelocity = initialVelocity;
    this.velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  }

  public void run() {
    update();
    display();
  }

  private void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(maxspeed);
    trail.add(position.copy());
    position.add(velocity);
    occurOtherCurves();
    arriveBorders();
    path.add(position.copy());

    acceleration.mult(0);  
  }

  private void display() {
    beginShape();
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);
    noFill();
    for(PVector v : path) {
      vertex(v.x, v.y);
    }
  }

  public void followField(Field field) { 
    PVector desired = field.lookup(initialVelocity);  
    desired.mult(maxspeed);
    PVector steer = PVector.sub(desired, velocity);
    steer.limit(maxforce);
    applyForce(steer);
  }

  private void applyForce(PVector force) {
    acceleration.add(force);
  }

  public boolean isEndMove(){
    return !life;
  }

  private void arriveBorders(){
    if(position.x <= 0 || position.x >= width || position.y <= 0 || position.y >= height)
      life = false;
  }

  private void occurOtherCurves() {
    for(PVector p : trail) {
      if(p.x == position.x && p.y == position.y) life = false;          
    }  
  }

  public ArrayList<PVector> getPath() {
    return path;
  }
}
```

in `occurOtherCurves()` function ,`ArrayList<PVector> trail` is a global variable used to record the positions that all particles  passed through,but it didn't work.
thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.

But generally, it sounds like what you'd want to do is check whether a new path segment intersects with any existing path segments. If it does, then truncate it at the intersection point (or just don't add it) and stop adding path segments to that path.

You'll have much better luck if you break your problem down into smaller pieces, and take on one piece at a time. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question. Good luck.